# Difference between In'ride 100 and 300

Tags: turbo-trainer

In India both the Btwin In'ride 100 and 300 trainers are of the same price I.e 7k. Can anyone tell me the difference between the two. From the description on the website I can't say that I can find any difference apart from the fact that 300 offers 6 resistances and 100 offers 7 resistances.which one is better to buy wrt better efficiency,  less noise and durability.

Comment: There seems to be no stock of the 300 here in the UK so can't compare.  If it's not over budget stepping up the the 500 (fluid resistance and a larger flywheel) would be highly recommended.  Fluid trainers are typically less noisy and give a much better 'road feel'